# T Sql Column only fills with null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our team had an issue where a stored procedure did not fill every column with data. The stored procedure fills  table from a view. We manually ran select statements from the view and the expected data was there. However when we ran Insert statements three columns in the middle of the table where null filled.

```
 Insert into Table2
 Select * from View1
```

Did not fill specific columns. We tested several times.
The columns not filled where Table2.Num1,Table2.Num2,Table2.Num3. All values for these fields where null.

```
Select * from View1
```

All the data was present. View1.Num1, View1.Num2, View1.Num3. These where nvarchar(16) fields filled with numeric data.

```
Truncate Table2
Insert into Table2
Select * from View1
```

The same specific columns where not filling. The rest of the table did fine.

```
Created Table3 based on Table2.

Insert into Table3
Select * from View1
```

Worked fine, all the data was there.

Does someone know why an instance like this might happen?

**Extra info requested**

The table structure between the two tables is the same.

The specific columns having an issue are varchar(16)

**What does created table3 mean?**

We generated Create table2 statement, then renamed it to Table3 and executed it. Table3 is identical to table2.

**Table structure**

This is the statement used to create table2. The identical create statement is used for table3 except the table name is changed. The view has the same number of columns with the same names and definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
[emp_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[company] [char](4) NULL,
[empno] [int] NOT NULL,
[termination_date] [datetime] NULL,
[rehire_date] [datetime] NULL,
[hire_date] [datetime] NULL,
[first_name] [varchar](128) NULL,
[last_name] [varchar](128) NULL,
[middle_name] [varchar](128) NULL,
[aka] [varchar](128) NULL,
[soc_sec_no] [char](9) NULL,
[birth_date] [datetime] NULL,
[sex] [char](1) NULL,
[race] [char](1) NULL,
[marital_status] [char](1) NULL,
[disability] [char](1) NULL,
[citizenship] [char](4) NULL,
[military] [char](1) NULL,
[union_code] [char](8) NULL,
[eeo_loc] [varchar](254) NULL,
[pers_status] [char](1) NULL,
[employ_type] [char](2) NULL,
[normal_hours] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
[week_over_hours] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
[adj_service_date] [datetime] NULL,
[shift] [char](8) NULL,
[visa_number] [char](30) NULL,
[visa_exp_date] [datetime] NULL,
[passport_number] [char](30) NULL,
[passport_exp_date] [datetime] NULL,
[process_cobra] [char](1) NULL,
[maiden_name] [varchar](128) NULL,
[Visa ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
[Visa Type Name] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
[TA_Source] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[LW_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
[LW_ID_Type] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
[Taleo_ID] [varchar](254) NULL,
[Uses_Tobacco] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
[Source_DB] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[UserID] [varchar](254) NULL,
[Num1] [varchar](16) NULL,
[Num2] [varchar](16) NULL,
[Num3] [varchar](16) NULL,
[AFF_EmpID] [int] NULL,
[MHC_EmpID] [int] NULL,
[daily_hours] [decimal](12, 2) NULL,
[Orig_Hire_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[WD_Continuous_Service_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Hire_Date_PM] [datetime] NULL,
[CompanyServiceDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Prim_Order] [bigint] NULL,
[AD_Domain] [varchar](128) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[empno] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, just went back in to reformat and you'd already gotten to it.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the columns so we have some clue as to what's going on? At the moment we are kind of forced to take your word for it which make it impossible to see what's happening and help you out. The results of selecting from table 1 would help as well.

Comment: How do you know the structures are the same? They use the same create statement? or did you create one through using `Select into`?

Comment: @Brad  My understanding is that when the table was initially created it was created using a Select Into statement, and then the table was tweaked slightly.

Comment: @PCSgtL tweaked how?! Post what these tables look like or we will not be able to help you.

Comment: `Select into` is not a direct copy or a table. It can miss things like constraints, nullability, and other things that can't be guessed based on the data you used to select into your new table. In SSMS jsut right click on your `table1` in the object browser and select `Create to` new window.

Comment: @PCSgtL I'd suggest editing your question to include all necessary details including table structures and even some sample data.  At this point, we are just guessing as to whether or not the tables are the same, etc.

Comment: Your update didn't answer my question. I give up you're on your own.

Comment: @Zane thanks for your initial willingness to help. I am a little hog tied in what I have access too since I've not been in my new position  long enough to have an OU account. Trying to troubleshoot over a co-workers shoulder.

Comment: Thanks for providing the `Create`. Now how does that compare to `Table1`? And what column is null? What should the value be?

Comment: Are there any `for insert`/`instead of insert` triggers on `table2`?

Comment: @Brad, sorry I missed that one reference. It is View1.  Num1, Num2,  an Num3 are the columns that are being filled only with Nulls. The values are numeric only strings. for example 123, 13865, 789342 ect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really be explicitly stating what columns go where and definitely not using a `Select *` on an `Insert`

```
 Insert into Table2(column1, column2, column3)
 Select column1, column2, column3
 from Table1
```

now you KNOW `Table1.Column1` maps to `Table2.Column2`

Comment: I agree Brad. However if the tables are the same, would that really cause a problem?

Comment: @PCSgtL do you we really know at this point that the tables are the same? I don't see much in the way of table structure in the question.

Comment: Maybe you can expand on what `Created Table3 based on Table2.` means.

Comment: I agree. Not explicitly stating columns will always cause problems like this. Once you implement an explicit list you'll probably find the issue goes away and then you'll have to work out why.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in confirming this. I believe this answer to be correct.